# Error using Twilio.api in C# DLL because it has no strong name

Tags: twilio

Any idea how to work around this?  I'm trying to use an example provided by Twilio to set this up, but I am getting the following error:

Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Twilio.Api' does not have a strong name

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you're referring to the issue described [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/79), which is not really a Twilio Library issue, but due to the fact we use RestSharp as a dependency.

> Since we take a dependency on RestSharp and they have decided not to
>   provide a strong named assembly, we will not be able to provide a
>   strong named assembly.
>
> Your certainly welcome to sign both assemblies yourself by either
>   downloading and recompiling the source with your key, or using a
>   post-compilation techniques such as the one described here:
>
> http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing

Hope this help you

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the API?  I setup a POC using clicatell and was able to use HTTP.  Can I do the same thing with Twilio?  I didn't see any C# examples, so I am not sure how to go about it.  But I did see that HTTP is supported.  Just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Yeah, you can just use the REST api directly to communicate with Twilio. If you look at the JSON exampled here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages, it shows you how you can accomplish the same thing by just making HTTP requests.